# Landau's argument of Conservation of Momentum

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

I am stuck on the conservation of momentum proof given in Landau Volume 1 book of Classical mechanics.

Here is my attempt:

Definition of homogenity of space at least what I think is if we parallel transport the whole system to any other arbitrary position, the equations of motion would be unaffected.

Now as done in Landau book:
$\delta L = \frac {\partial L}{\partial q} \delta q$

Now as we know $\delta q$ is arbitrary and by the definition of homogenity , the equations of motions should be unaffected i.e. $\delta L = \dfrac{df(q,t)}{dt}$ as the two distinct Lagrangians will give same EOMs if they differ by $\dfrac{df(q,t)}{dt}$, but the book contradicts at this point and says $ \delta L =0$

Can you please clarify if my argument holds any ground and if so, what can I interpret more from this, because our final aim was to derive if the momentum is conserved from homogenity of space.

Comment: As I understand it, $\delta L = L_2 -L_1$ where $L_2$ is the lagrangian when the whole system is parallel transported and $L_1$ is the lagrangian in the original system.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what the book is considering arbitrary is $\epsilon$ not the coordinate. In my version of the book I have the following:
$$
\delta L=\sum_a\frac{\partial L}{\partial r_a}\cdot\delta r_a=\epsilon\sum_a\frac{\partial L}{\partial r_a}=0
$$
So, now Landau says that the displacement $\epsilon$ is arbitrary and he is free to assume is cero. What he is doing here is to analyze the case in which the lagrangian is defined on your initial coordinate system. This works as proof because of the argument of homogeneous space. That means that there's no reason to think anything would change if you define your coordinate system 1 m away.
I understand why you feel like that, it feels a bit like cheating but this is ok. Then, with $\delta L=0$ he proceeds to calculate if his assumption was correct and if the momentum really is a conservated quantity. Before this, in the derivation of Euler-Lagrange equations, you can see why he is taking $\delta L=0$. I think that you should check out Goldstein's proof, I have found that Goldstein tends to explain a bit more than Landau. Briefly, what Goldstein does I to show that the momentum can be written like
$$
P_{i}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q_i}}=m\dot{q_i}+c
$$
and then, assuming a cyclic coordinate, the Euler-Lagrange equations becomes
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_i}}=0
$$
which means
$$
\frac{d}{dt}P_i=0
$$
So you see that momentum is conserved over time. This way you don't have to mess up with weird arguments.

Comment: Firstly, I appreciate your answer. My doubt specifically is where you said "there's no reason to think anything would change if you define your coordinate system 1 m away" and then further you said, "with δL=0 he proceeds to calculate if his assumption was correct..." Now my doubt is that as by homogeneity of space nothing should be changed by transporting my whole system by 1 meter therefore my EOMs should be invariant i.e. difference in the lagrangians of the original system and the transported system should be equal to $ \dfrac {df}{dt}$ where f(q,t). This last argument is used in chapter1.

Comment: Well, I think that you are missing the point of the chapter 1 idea. He is showing that the minimum action principle works for $L^\prime$ as well as for $L$. There fore adding that $\frac{df}{dt}$ doesn't change the lagrangian, so what he does for momentum doesn't need to take into account that. Remember that EOM come from the minimal action principle. Not from the form of the lagrangian.